# rbinom for rolling a 111-side die 104 times in r

Tags: r, random

i understand if you roll a 100-side die 100 times for a total number of 7s.  you get

```
  rbinom(1,100,0.07)
```

but how do you roll a 111-sided die 104 times and get the total number of 34s you get?  kinda confused.

Comment: wouldn't be rbinom(104,111, ???)

Comment: This sounds like a statistics homework question rather than a programming question. Not even sure if you are trying to calculate a probability or expected value. This question isn't very clear at all.

Comment: @MrFlick yup.  roll a 111-sided die 104 times and report the total number of 34s you get. my question is how could you figure out the probability of 34s you get to fulfill the third argument in the rbinom function.

Comment: I would guess there's only 1 number 34 on the 111 sided dice so the change of rolling one in one toss is 1/111. Which also means I don't think your first statement is correct about the 7's.

Comment: @MrFlick it should be 1/100 right?

Comment: @MrFlick thanks! i got it!

Answer (score 0):

rbinom(number of experiments, number of observations per experiment, probability of success)

We wanted to simulate rolling a 111-side dice 104 times, and we wished to count the number of 34's you observe. Like @mrflick mentioned, we only have one chance to get 34's out of the 111-side dice. Then i think the code would be,

```
 rbinom(1,104,1/111)
```

Comment: @JohnColeman i doubt. another way to realize the conditions is to sum all the  rbinom(111,104,1/111)